# defining object location by it's center point

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

In c# .net 4 forms whenever I add an object, it's location is determined by it's top-left corner.
This means, that if I resize this object, it will be resized from this point.

I have a picture box. if I change the width and height to something smaller, then the picture box seems like it moved, since it's borders are now much closer to it's top-left, moving the picture-box center point.

I want the picture-box to rescale while maintaining it's position - meaning the center point of the picture will stay the same, while the size will be split around this point (half-up half-down and half-left half-right).

Is that possible?

Comment: are you using anchors?

Comment: yes it is anchored to the left and to the top. To try removing this? but then resising the window will cause the object to move though. Do you think it will solve my issue? I dont see how its relevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is off my mind and crafted quickly but something like:

```
void resizeFromCenter(PictureBox box, int w, int h)
{
  var cenx = box.Left + box.Width/2;
  var ceny = box.Top + box.Height/2;
  box.Left = cenx - w/2;
  box.Width = w;
  box.Top = ceny - h/2;
  box.Height = h;
}
```

Comment: Not guaranteed and totally untested, by the way

Comment: that seems to be on the right direction... I will check this out